# error installing flutter in ubuntu 18.04: "Android license status unknown"

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

1. I followed all the steps to install flutter in the web
2. When finished, I tried the command in the terminal: $ flutter doctor -v
3. the result was all good except one:

   [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
       • Android SDK at /home/agung/Android/Sdk
       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
       • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
       • Java binary at: /home/agung/android-studio/jre/bin/java
       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
       ✗ Android license status unknown.
         Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
         See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
4. I tried some tips, the last tips I used was: installing java with this:
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
   and change the java with this:
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
   and I tried any combinations, but nothing works. (I have followed any tips in stakeoverflow but nothing works)

How to fix this? To make result of 'flutter doctor -v' good?

Answer (score 0):

Try following the install instructions in the official flutter site. The specific part on android licenses is here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup

In short: install Android Studio, install the sdks through Android Studio and accept the licenses there. The link goes into details as to why. Afterwards flutter doctor should return just peachy

**Do notice that these are the instructions for Linux**. Follow this link to pick your own OS and read the appropriate guide: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Answer (score 0):

In console run:
`flutter doctor --android-licenses` and answer y to all